# Wordwrap vs. Newline UIButton stretching

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, line-breaks, word-wrap

I have a `UIButton` and I need to be able to set its label to any text, and therefore it needs to stretch vertically.

When setting the text with `\n` characters the UIButton expands correctly:

```
self.myButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.myButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
self.myButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[self.myButton setTitle:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer \nadipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh \neuismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore \nmagna aliquam erat volutpat. \nUt wisi enim ad minim veniam, \nquis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper \nsuscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex \nea commodo consequat." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image]

But when I don't have any `\n` and instead let the label line-break itself based on the content, the lines don't seem to matter to the `UIButton` height

```
self.myButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.myButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
self.myButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[self.myButton setTitle:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image]

Is there a configuration on `UIButton` or its `UILabel` that controls this behavior or is this an iOS bug? (Running on iOS 9.1)

***NOTE:*** I'm not really interested in manually re-calculating the frame size of the UIButton each time the text is changed, I'm wondering if there's an autolayout constraint or config property on UIButton to get the right behavior

Comment: try self.myButton.clipsToBounds = YES;

Comment: @MGP clipsToBounds will only crop it to the green rectangle, it will not expand to look like the top image unfortunately

Comment: Have you used AutoLayout?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a subclass of `UIButton` in which you override `intrinsicContentSize`:

```
@implementation HeightExpandingButton

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    CGFloat width = self.bounds.size.width;
    CGSize labelSize = [self.titleLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, 100000)];
    labelSize.width = width;
    return labelSize;
}

@end
```

Result:

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks. But trying this on the simulator I need set width to self.bounds.size.width / 2 to get the right height. Does this solution also require keeping track of pixel density?

Comment: No. I ran on the simulator and didn't have to do that. Does your button have a transform?

Comment: I realize what's wrong now. I had pinned the button to the leading and trailing edge of the screen in autolayout, apparently self.bounds.size.width doesn't work if you do that. When I set it to a fixed width your method works. Do you know if it's possible to do it using leading/trailing constraints instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use following to achieve that. Frame of the button will be calculated as per the text.

```
[button sizeToFit];
```

Or you can try this

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *textStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
textStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
textStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14],NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:textStyle};
button.frame.size = [buttonTitle sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
[button setTitle:buttonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

or

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize;   //set maximum able size that you can afford. CGSizeMake(310, CGFLOAT_MAX); or CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX,310);
CGRect textRect = [buttonTitle boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize   
                                     options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                  attributes:attributes
                                     context:nil];
```

You can add extra padding if needed.

Comment: sizeToFit didn't work :(. And in the second method, there's no attribute saying where to linebreak? It hence gives me: CGSize (width = 1723.3300000000022, height = 16.309999999999999) since it's the width of all the text without linebreaks

Comment: You can use NSParagraphStyleAttributeName. Check the edit

Comment: It doesn't work either unfortunately. But if the attributes have no connection to the UIButton's width in any way, how will it possibly now where to linebreak?

Comment: Ya sorry, that got off my mind. Unless you fix either of width or height it wouldn't be possible. if you fix either one, you can use `boundingRectWithSize`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
- (CGSize)getDynamicSizeWithText:(NSString *)text {
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width ,CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGRect expectedLabelSize = [text boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f], NSFontAttributeName : text} context:nil];
    return expectedLabelSize.size;
}
```

And then....

```
//title = text to display on button

CGSize size = [self getDynamicSizeWithText:title];

[self.myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(self.myButton.frame.origin.x, self.myButton.frame.origin.y, size.width, size.height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't used the AutoLayout then please try below code. Hope its work for you.

```
self.myButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines=0;
self.myButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
NSString *titleOfButton=@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.";
[self.myButton setTitle:titleOfButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
CGSize constraint1=CGSizeMake(YOUR_BUTTON_WIDTH, 5000.0f);
CGSize size1=[titleOfButton sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:constraint1 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[self.myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(self.myButton.frame.origin.x, self.myButton.frame.origin.y, self.myButton.frame.size.width, size1.height+20)];
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, size1 does give a proper height! However, sizeWithFont is deprecated since iOS7.0 apparently. Also, my question is if there's a way to configure the UIButton to get the right behavior, not if it's possible to manually resize it each time the text changes. I'll edit my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate your button title. It's the easiest way to do it. Try this;

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15]}; 
CGSize size1 = [self.myButton.titleLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
```